# Can I Add Emoji Icon in my Project Name in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, emoji

I have been wondering whether we can add emoji icon in the project name of an iOS project. Do apple reject app if the app name have emoji icon?

I tried to add emoji in my project name and i successfully added the emoji icon in my app name. But i just want to know that is it legal?

Comment: At `Entering Your App’s Name` section there's nothing said about emoji http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1 I think having `only` emoji as the name is not appropriate name. Out of curiosity, are you saying it is displayed as an icon, not text ?

Comment: The thing is i thought of naming my app with the combination of text and emoji... Anyhow just now it strikes me with rdurand answer that when i search apps with emoji there are apps with names containing emoji... SO i think m good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no source other than my experience, but it looks like Apple allows it. If you search the word "emoji" on your iDevice on the AppStore, you'll find multiple apps with emoji icons in their title. There's no reason why they approved those and would reject yours. The only downside is that it's not searchable.

Comment: Is that still true? I did not find any app with emoji in title. Can you show an example?

Comment: @PEZO: probably not, I couldn't find any either anymore

Answer (score 0):

I think now in 2019 the answer is no. I could not find any app which uses an emoji in title/subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 5, 2023, I can confirm that emojis are allowed in the title displayed on a device. My latest app was approved yesterday and is available for download. Here's a screenshot from my iPhone 13 Pro Max:

[App icon and title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o4fe.png)

Comment: Can't find it in app store on my phone. Can you post a link to app store?

Comment: I won't post a link as to not advertise my app. Yet if you look at my linked image, search the App Store for the title without the emoji. I just checked to confirm the app is there.